# How to play video from Salesforce file in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe, video

There are few videos in files (Lightning files) of my slesforce org. Is there a way i can play/preview them in an iframe inside a lightning component?

Answer (score 3):

I normally use this approach for expose video files in my lightning components:

```
<video width="100%">
    <source src="{!'../sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + file.Id}" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser dont support video tag
</video>
```

You need acces to the file in order to see the file.

Comment: exposing video via file does not work anymore, getting error : `Refused to load media from 'https://urldomain.my.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/xxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self' *` any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

This approach work for me.

```
<video autoplay="true" muted="true" loop="true" id="myVideo">
        <source src="{!$Resource.VideoStaticResource}" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Can you please check, this works for you?