# How to play video from salesforce publicly distributed file

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community

```
We have a requirement to play MP4 content version file in the community using public URL. I tried with the iFrame tag but it is showing no preview available.
```

[image]

**Can anyone please help.**

Comment: Seems related to https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpVPAA0. Does the solution in this link work in your scenario?Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need a separate page on the community for particular file (Content version) URLs. I already looked into this solution but it will not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After investigation, I found one solution and it works for me.

```
Go to Setup -> Search for ‘File Upload and Download Security’.
Click on Edit and scroll for the file type ‘.mp4’ and set the ‘Download behavior’ as ‘Execute in Browser’. And that’s it! You’re all done.
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this issue. The SF download link is not a sufficient URL to play media (video or file). I recommend either coding a custom lightning component to play the video or go to the app Exchange. Please see links for details.

[How to play video from Salesforce file in lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/236279/how-to-play-video-from-salesforce-file-in-lightning-component)

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ed00FUAR

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I need to open mp4 on page directly.